# how to fix required a bean of type and This application has no explicit mapping for /error in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hexagonal-architecture

here is the aborescence of the packages

```
com
  +-bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management
      +-GestionBassTransApplication.java
      |
      +-worker
          +-adaters
          |  +-in
          |  |   +-WorkerController.java (Rest controller use ListOfWorkerImpl)
          |  +-out
          |      +-ListWorkerImpl.java (class implements ListOfWorkerRepository)
          +-application
          |   +-port
          |         +-in
          |         |  +-ListOfWorker.java (interface)
          |         +-out
          |             +-ListOfWorkerRepository.java (interface)
          +-usecase
               +-ListOfWorkerImpl (class implements ListOfWorker)
```

// here is my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping()
public class WorkerController {
    
    private ListOfWorker listOfWorker;
    
    @Autowired
    public WorkerController(ListOfWorker listOfWorker) {
        this.listOfWorker = listOfWorker;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/listWorkers")
    public List<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return listOfWorker.findAll();
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){       
        return "Hello";
    }}
```

To solve the error concerning required a bean of type... i use this solution

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.out.ListOfWorkerRepository",
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.in.ListOfWorker"
//....)}
```

now i found
`This application has no explicit mapping for /error in spring boot`
to resolved i use

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
  "bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.adapters.in"
//...)}
```

after that line **required a bean of type...** reappears

i thing that is caus of
 `bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.adapters.in.WorkerController`

// main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.out.ListOfWorkerRepository",
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.in.ListOfWorker",
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.adapters.in.WorkerController",
"bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.adapters.in",
})
public class GestionBassTransApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GestionBassTransApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }

}
```

// complete error

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.adapters.in.WorkerController required a bean of type 'bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.in.ListOfWorker' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'bj.com.bass_trans.java_spring_eclips_management.worker.application.port.in.ListOfWorker' in your configuration.
```

// This application has no explicit mapping...

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 13 15:24:37 WAT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

how  how can i solve these errors

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to make ListOfWorkerImpl as bean (put @Component at the class)

Comment: error still persists after adding @Component in ListOfWorkerImpl class

Comment: You should use names of the packages, not names of classes in the `scanBasePackages` value of `@SpringBootApplication` (first 3 entries are class names)